# MFC Command Window Command

Tags: c++, mfc

In MFC I want to Create a process by opening Command Window and executing a command in that say open notepad.
i Found this tried it didn't work

```
STARTUPINFO sInfo = {0};
sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo = {0};

CreateProcess("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",""0,0,TRUE,
NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo);
```

Comment: *"It didn't work"* is not a problem description. A problem description must include the expected behavior, as well as the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not telling cmd to do anything. Try this:

```
CreateProcess(0, "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe /c notepad.exe", 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &sInfo, &pInfo);
```

But maybe this is easier

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C notepad.exe", 0, SW_HIDE);
```

Or even this:

```
system("notepad.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the MSDN document we can see, you don't specify the second parameter that is the command line to excute.

On the other hand, there are no `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` enum item for the sixth parameter. You should do like this:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };   
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;   

si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;   
si.wShowWindow = TRUE;  
TCHAR cmdline[] =TEXT(" notepad.exe");   
BOOL bRet = ::CreateProcess (   
    TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"),  
    cmdline,    
    NULL,   
    NULL,   
    FALSE,   
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,   
    NULL,   
    NULL,   
    &si,   
    &pi);
```